# count occurrences with dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have following `Dataframe`:

```
               fk  name
0              105  Coca-Cola1 
1              105  Coca-Cola1
2              106  Coca-Cola2
3              115  Coca-Cola5
4              115  Coca-Cola5
5              115  Coca-Cola5
6              108  Coca-Cola8
7              105  Coca-Cola1
```

I want to count frequency of occurrences:

```
[[105, Coca-Cola1, 3],
 [106, Coca-Cola2, 1],
 [115, Coca-Cola5, 3],
 [108, Coca-Cola8, 1]]
```

Any idea how to get so ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with aggregating [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html), then [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and last convert to `numpy array` by [`DataFrame.values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) with [`numpy.ndarray.tolist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html):

```
df = df.groupby(['fk','name']).size().reset_index().values.tolist()
print (df)
[[105, 'Coca-Cola1', 3], 
 [106, 'Coca-Cola2', 1], 
 [108, 'Coca-Cola8', 1], 
 [115, 'Coca-Cola5', 3]]
```

If is order important add parameter `sort=False` to `groupby`:

```
df = df.groupby(['fk','name'], sort=False).size().reset_index().values.tolist()
print (df)
[[105, 'Coca-Cola1', 3], 
 [106, 'Coca-Cola2', 1], 
 [115, 'Coca-Cola5', 3], 
 [108, 'Coca-Cola8', 1]]
```

Comment: a trivial change - `sort=False` to retain the order.

Comment: @NickilMaveli - Thank you.